# Emulating ionic app absence of live reload

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

While running my ionic application with the command

```
ionic emulate android -l
```

It works fine when i do the same in absence of live reload as

```
ionic emulate android
```

I could not navigate to next page its giving error as

> APPLICATION ERROR net:: err file not found(file:///menu.html)

why it is so?
why i am not able to navigate with out using live reload?
I have included cordova whitelist also.

Answer (score 0):

Did you comlpete the build before emulation?
Try to run

```
ionic build android
```

and only after that:

```
ionic emulate android
```

Livereload is making a build for you but standalone run/emulate seems not - you have to explicitly do that.